# What is "modloop" option in Alpine?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel, kernel-module, alpine-linux

I'm trying to understand what is the difference of making Alpine installation medium as read-only type (LiveCD) and as a standard disk mode (where the OS state can be saved). I've seen the `modloop` option when the author of this article (https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Create_UEFI_boot_USB) configured loader entries for UEFI boot mode:

```
Contents of loader/entries/alpine.conf
title    Alpine Linux
linux    /boot/vmlinuz-hardened
initrd   /boot/initramfs-hardened
options  modloop=/boot/modloop-hardened modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod,usb-storage quiet
```

And the question is how options listed in this stanza `modloop=/boot/modloop-hardened modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod` are related to each other and what do they mean?

Comment: Yes I did. After installing `man man-pages` I tried to grep-ing "modloop" within the whole man pages. As you might guess `man modloop` gives nothing as well.

Answer (score 10):

The `modloop=` option specifies a SquashFS filesystem that gets mounted to `/.modloop` by the init file `/etc/init.d/modloop` and symlinked from `/lib/modules` (or possibly union-mounted with the overlay - see the `modloop` init script for details). It contains the full kernel module tree for the built kernel, not the more limited set included in the initramfs / initrd.

You might find these helpful to explore:

- `unsquashfs -l /boot/modloop-hardened` (to explore what will get mounted to `/.modloop`)
- `gzip -dc /boot/initramfs-hardened | cpio -it` (to explore the initramfs contents)